# Stemmer/lemmatizer for Polish language

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for a stemmer/lemmatizer for Polish language, preferably in Python. What would you recommend?

I have a list of ingredients in a recipe. Plural forms are inflected differently, depending on the counter, e.g.: for tomatoes

> 5 pomidorów
>
> 2 pomidory
>
> 1 pomidor

I want my parser to recognize all those ingredients as for one product, hence the need for stemming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is bunch of lemmatization solutions for polish language. 
One of the best implementation is in polish morphosyntactic analyser, which you can download [here](http://sgjp.pl/morfeusz/dopobrania.html.en).

It has bindings to python, but you have to install them manually. It is "morphosyntactic analyser" which means, that you get all possible lemmas for a given word. If you want also disambiguation, you can use [this tool](http://zil.ipipan.waw.pl/LemmaPL) which is provided as docker container.

My team is currently working on implementing polish language support for [Spacy](https://spacy.io/), and we will cover lemmatization, so tool with good integration and support will be available soon.

Comment: amazing! What tools are you using for that? Is there any web page about the project?

Comment: @MkL We have just started, and we don't have website about, but if you are interested follow spacy pull requests, i think our PR with tokenizer will be ready next week, and lemmatizer in 2 weeks.

Comment: @Gizio Will you have any plans to implement full model for polish language in spacy?

Comment: Thanks. Do you have plans to include lemma disambiguation into SpaCy? Using docker container is a way to start but does not sound very scallable.

Answer (score 2):

I have ported Stempel Stemmer from Java to Python:
https://github.com/dzieciou/pystempel and improved its effectiveness by pretraining stemming tables on Polimorf dictionary from Morfeusz.

It appears slightly faster than wrapping Java implementation with pyjini but the main point is that I do not have to mix multiple languages in one project, avoiding debugging across Python and Java.

Answer (score 1):

In PolEval 2017 was a [POS Tagging task](http://2017.poleval.pl/index.php/tasks/) with Lemmatisation subtask. The winning solution KRNNT obtained about [98% of accuracy](http://2017.poleval.pl/index.php/results/) in this subtask. [KRNNT](https://github.com/kwrobel-nlp/krnnt) is available also as a docker image.
The results of tagging for your example is (in TSV format):

```
5   5   num:pl:nom:m3:rec
pomidorów   pomidor subst:pl:gen:m3

2   2   num:pl:acc:m3:congr
pomidory    pomidor subst:pl:nom:m3

1   1   adj:sg:nom:m3:pos
pomidor pomidor subst:sg:nom:m3
```

As you can see, in the second column the lemma is `pomidor` (and the third column is POS tag).